# change the this.Apiurl in js file using powershell

Tags: javascript, powershell

I have main.bundle.js file. In that particular file I need to change the url of this.ApiUrl = "http://localhost:xxxxx/"; with my own url. This change has to be done using powershell script.

```
$uri="xxxxxx.net";
$path= "D:\main.bundle.js"
$content= Get-Content -Path
$path | Select-String "this.ApiUrl = """ | foreach-object {
    $_ -replace "this.ApiUrl = """, "this.ApiUrl = ""$uri"
} (
    Get-Content $path).replace("this.ApiUrl = """,$content
) | Set-Content $path
```

Comment: What do you tried so far ?

Answer (score -1):

In powershell you can use

```
cat main.bundle.js | % { $_ -replace "http://localhost:xxxx","http://your_url:yyyy" }
```

Comment: We have to get that url dynamically from the js file and replace it with our url

$uri="http://xxxxxxx.net"
$path= "D:\main.bundle.js"


$content= Get-Content -Path $path | Select-String "this.ApiUrl = """ | foreach-object {$_ -replace "this.ApiUrl = """, "this.ApiUrl = ""$uri"} 


(Get-Content $path).replace("this.ApiUrl = """,$content) | Set-Content $path

Comment: I think Ngalims answer is correct, but without actual content of your main.bundle.js file it is impossible to say what the urls in that file look like..
Anyway, you are over complicating the thing. Why not simply do `$uri="xxxxxxx.net"; $path= "D:\main.bundle.js"; $content= Get-Content -Path $path -Raw -replace "this.ApiUrl\s*=.*", "this.ApiUrl = $uri"; Set-Content -Value $content -Path $path -Force`

Comment: @Theo I have tired it but I am getting the url Multiple times like

"this.ApiUrl = http://xxxx.net
    //           this.ApiUrl = http://xxxx.net"

Comment: You REALLY should give us an examlpe of your main.bundle.js file in order to be able to see what exactly is in there and how to help you with this.
The double-forward-slash in the file is the way JavaScript tells the interpreter that what follows is comment and should be ignored. It is possible this comment intended to keep the original url, but the code now is set to replace all occurrences.